# Open Source licensing on libraries & DLL's

Tags: dll, open-source, licensing

Most of you know that the main purpose of Open Source libraries' licensing is to distribute the source code along with your application.

Well - commercially this still applies - regardless if it's GPL or LGPL.
Not that I know extremely much about it's tweaks or rules - that's why I'm asking here.

However - I personally wish to keep some code closed source.
My question is:

**If I do use an external open source library (which I'll gladly release the code)**

&

**it will import functions from a closed source DLL -** (definitions only)

**does that mean I'm allowed to NOT distribute my DLL's code?**

Comment: You'll need to provide more information.  What license(s) is the code you want to use released under?  Is the external code used by core features of your program or plug-ins the program would run happily without?

Comment: The program wouldn't be able to function at all without this core DLL unfortunately. The library I'm using is under LGPL & allows static linking. However, I won't statically link my own DLL.

Comment: Ok, sounds like you would be able to keep your source closed then.  LGPL demands that your users can integrate a new version of the LGPL'd library themselves.  If you plan to release that library as a separate binary, all users immediately have the ability to replace it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Comment: I have created a Q&A proposal at area51 regarding open source licensing: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58715/open-source-licensing.  If it interests you, you can vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GNU's LGPL.

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License):

> The GNU Lesser General Public License or LGPL (formerly the GNU Library General Public License) is a free software license published by the Free Software Foundation (FSF). The LGPL allows developers and companies to use and integrate LGPL software into their own (**even proprietary**) software **without being required (by the terms of a strong copyleft) to release the source code of their own software-parts**.

(Emphasis mine).

And here is a link to the [GNU LGPL official page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License).